# How to know if an hour this in between two times with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this:

```
DECLARE @HourBegin time = '18:00'
DECLARE @HourEnd time = '02:00'
DECLARE @Hour TIME = '20:00'

BEGIN TRAN 
    IF(@Hour between @HourBegin and @HourEnd)
    BEGIN   
        SELECT  
            CONVERT(BIT, 1) AS ERROR, 
            '1'  AS MSG     
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
        SELECT  
            CONVERT(BIT,1) AS ERROR, 
            '0'  AS MSG     
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

The is problem is that the variable `@HourEnd` is the next day then the `BETWEEN` always gives me the variable `@Hour` is not within the specified range

!HELP!

Comment: Are you actually running into this issue in your database, or are you just messing with variables?  `DateTime` may be better suited for what you're trying to accomplish, because unless I missed some major maths change, 20 isn't between 2 and 18.

Comment: Aye - there's nothing to go from here - there is no date portion in your variables to compare against! Also no idea why you are bothering with a transaction when there's no changes being made

Comment: I have this in a stored procedure, and only have time type variables undated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. If you get `endDate < StartDate` you probably should add 1 day to endDate. So you end up with:

```
DECLARE @HourBegin time = '18:00'
DECLARE @HourEnd time = '02:00'
DECLARE @Hour TIME = '19:00'

DECLARE @DateBegin DATETIME
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME
DECLARE @Date DATETIME

select @DateBegin = CAST(@HourBegin AS DATETIME)
select @DateEnd = CAST(@HourEnd AS DATETIME)
select @Date = CAST(@Hour AS DATETIME)

IF(@DateEnd < @DateBegin)
    SET @DateEnd = DATEADD(dd, 1, @DateEnd)

BEGIN TRAN 
    IF(@Date between @DateBegin and @DateEnd)
    BEGIN   
            SELECT  CONVERT(BIT,1) AS ERROR, '1'  AS MSG     
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
            SELECT  CONVERT(BIT,1) AS ERROR, '0'  AS MSG     
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: works well with the hours before midnight , but if the time is 1:00 gives problems

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to handle this:

```
CREATE function dbo.f_between
(
  @HourBegin DATETIME,
  @HourEnd DATETIME,
  @Hour DATETIME
)RETURNS bit
as
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN
    @Hour between @HourBegin and @HourEnd or
   ((@Hour <= @HourEnd or @hour >= @HourBegin) and @HourBegin > @HourEnd) 
   THEN cast(1 as bit) 
ELSE cast(0 as bit) END
END
```

Here is an example how to use it:

Test data and table:

```
DECLARE @t table(HourBegin time, HourEnd time, hour time)
insert @t values('06:00', '12:00', '01:00') -- not between
insert @t values('06:00', '12:00', '09:00') -- between
insert @t values('06:00', '12:00', '15:00') -- not between
insert @t values('12:00', '06:00', '01:00') -- between
insert @t values('12:00', '06:00', '09:00') -- not between
insert @t values('12:00', '06:00', '15:00') -- between
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  HourBegin, 
  HourEnd, 
  hour, 
  dbo.f_between(HourBegin, HourEnd, hour) betweenbit
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
HourBegin  HourEnd   hour      betweenbit
06:00:00   12:00:00  01:00:00  0
06:00:00   12:00:00  09:00:00  1
06:00:00   12:00:00  15:00:00  0
12:00:00   06:00:00  01:00:00  1
12:00:00   06:00:00  09:00:00  0
12:00:00   06:00:00  15:00:00  1
```